# SQL selecting the rows with latest datetime group by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a database with a number of tables that look like this (simplified a bit)

```
    id |  item_id  | type_id |  processed_time      |  other cols
 ------|-----------|---------|----------------------|-------------
     1 |         1 |       1 |  2015-03-17 00:11:22 |    ...
     2 |         1 |       1 |  2015-03-17 00:22:33 |    ...
     3 |         1 |       2 |  2015-03-17 00:11:22 |    ...
     4 |         1 |       2 |  2015-03-17 00:33:44 |    ...
     5 |         2 |       1 |  2015-03-17 00:22:33 |    ...
     6 |         2 |       1 |  2015-03-17 00:11:22 |    ...
     7 |         2 |       2 |  2015-03-17 00:22:33 |    ...
     8 |         2 |       2 |  2015-03-17 00:33:44 |    ...
   ... |       ... |     ... |                  ... |    ...
```

I am trying to execute a number of queries, but they all follow the same theme:
selecting all the latest (processed time (datetime)) rows for a specific item(s) grouped by type_id.

So with the table example, one would expect, for item_id=1 to get:

```
    id |  item_id  | type_id |  processed_time      |  other cols
 ------|-----------|---------|----------------------|-------------
     2 |         1 |       1 |  2015-03-17 00:22:33 |    ...
     4 |         1 |       2 |  2015-03-17 00:33:44 |    ...
   ... |       ... |     ... |                  ... |    ...
```

In addition to that, I would like to perform this query for all the items, I.E:

```
    id |  item_id  | type_id |  processed_time      |  other cols
 ------|-----------|---------|----------------------|-------------
     2 |         1 |       1 |  2015-03-17 00:22:33 |    ...
     4 |         1 |       2 |  2015-03-17 00:33:44 |    ...
     5 |         2 |       1 |  2015-03-17 00:22:33 |    ...
     8 |         2 |       2 |  2015-03-17 00:33:44 |    ...
   ... |       ... |     ... |                  ... |    ...
```

The main issue I'm running into is I'm not really sure how to get the id after grabbing the most recent processed time. The direction I keep heading toward is something along the lines of a subquery like `SELECT id, MAX(processed_time) FROM item GROUP BY type_id` however `id` in that query is clearly undefined and I'm not really sure how to get that value.

(note that processed_time is not unique)

Comment: What are your expected results from this? If that last table is your expected results, your question is not worded properly, because I don't see how that matches up with what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t2.item_id = t.item_id
                   AND t2.type_id = t.type_id 
                   AND t2.processed_time > t.processed_time
                   AND t2.id > t.id   -- (note that processed_time is not unique)
                 )
```

Return the last item for the same item_id and type_id

Comment: Awesome, that works. I kept trying to pick the right values; didn't even occur to me to try to do the opposite - exclude the ones I don't want instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion because your description and the second sample output doesn't match. It looks like you want to find the latest type_id within an item_id. In that case, from the data sample you show, there would four rows -- two for item_id = 1: type_id 1 and 2, and two for item_id = 2: type_id 1 and 2.

If that is the case, a simple correlated subquery would be one of your best methods.

```
select  *
from    Source s
where   s.processed_time =(
            select  Max( processed_time )
            from    Source
            where   item_id = s.item_id
                and type_id = s.type_id );
```

Which returns:

```
id item_id type_id processed_time
-- ------- ------- -------------------
2        1       1 2015-03-17 00:22:33
4        1       2 2015-03-17 00:33:44
5        2       1 2015-03-17 00:22:33
8        2       2 2015-03-17 00:33:44
```

It would help if there was an index on (item_id, type_id, processed_time).

If this is not what you're looking for, then please add some description.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it should only have 4 rows (ids 2,4,5,8) I corrected the example.

Comment: The solution seems incredibly simple and does appear to work, however it's insanely slow. Even specifying after specifying an  `item_id` it takes it over ~40 seconds to execute. (The table has millions of entries). Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an index on the three columns I suggested? That's one index with the columns, not three indexes.